# Where can I get dompdf_0-8-0 that include .info.yml files?

Tags: webforms

I am new to Drupal and can't get the download PDF feature working in Drupal 8 webform submission, getting the following message:

Error generating document: Missing dependencies. Please install with: composer require "dompdf/dompdf 0.8.0"

I have downloaded dompdf/dompdf 0.8.0 zip.file from here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.8.0 and coverted it to tar.gz (since zip upload is not working) and when trying to upload I am getting the following error:

dompdf_0-8-0.tar does not contain any .info.yml files.

Where can I get dompdf_0-8-0 that include .info.yml files?

Comment: dompdf_0-8-0 is an external library and not a Drupal module.  Composer is the easiest way to install DomPDF. @see https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf

Comment: Thank you very much!